# Light Source to Affect One Single Object in a Scene

Tags: objects, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting, scene

I have an object in a scene that uses multiple light sources, however, I only need the lights to hit the object and nothing else in the scene. Is there any way to fix this problem in Blender currently? Eevee is being used to render.

Comment: it seems there isn't yet a native solution: https://developer.blender.org/T68915

Comment: Yeap ... Compositing